# Ninject 3: How to use Named Bindings with Modules?

Tags: ninject

I am new to Ninject (using the latest v3).
I got the basics working fine (incl. named bindings without modules, i.e. on the kernel directly) but I can't get it to work with Modules.

The module looks like this:

```
public class MainModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<Window>().ToMethod(context => App.Current.MainWindow).Named("MainWindow");
    }
}
```

And I am using it like this:

```
    public MainViewModel Main
    {
        get
        {
            return kernel.Get<MainViewModel>("MainWindow");
        }
    }
```

which results in an ActivationException telling me that "no matching bindings are available". Without the named binding it works fine.

How do I use named bindings with modules?

Comment: You sure it's the same Kernel instance with the same Bindings definitely happening? When you inspect the kernel in the debugger?

Comment: The StandardKernel instance is a static member of the class:
private static StandardKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new MainModule());

I inspected the kernel in the debugger but could not find the bindings.

Your comment sounds like you would have expected the named setup in the module to work. Am I right in that assumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding `Window` but request a `MainViewModel`. There is no correlation between these two things. So I have no iead why you think this should work.

Without the name it works because self bindable objects like `MainViewModel` are implicitly bound to themself. That's why it is working.

Update:

If I understand you correctly then you want

```
Bind<Window>().ToMethod(context => App.Current.MainWindow).WhenParentNamed("MainWindow");
Bind<MainViewModel>().ToSelf().Named("MainWindow");
```

Comment: The MainViewModel constructor takes a Window as parameter. I want to make sure that it always gets App.Current.MainWindow. Other classes, however, that may also need a Window in the constructor may want different Windows, hence the naming. I know this can be achieved differently. I am just "playing" with Ninject to familiarize myself with it. You seem to be saying that I have fundamentally misunderstood something here?

Comment: Thanks, Remo. That did the trick and I now understand where I went wrong.